# WHMCS: How do I get the post data every time I submit the form on admin/configaddonmods.php page

Tags: php, whmcs

newb whmcs module addon dev. here.

I want to be able to get the posted data and module addon info when submit the form. I believe I need to add a hook.

However, this code doesn't fire when submit:

```php
add_hook('AddonConfigSave', 1, function($vars) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($vars);
    exit;
});
```

this is on admin/configaddonmods.php page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The `AddonConfigSave` hook point is currently not executing. You're not doing anything wrong, the developers just broke it at some point. I've tested with WHMCS 8.6 and 8.7 and have reported the issue to them. Hopefully, they'll fix it before releasing 8.7 in production but I highly doubt it.</strike>

Scratch the above. The `AddonConfigSave` hook point is for *product* addons. There's no hook point available to catch the data you're trying to catch, unfortunately.